# How to call exist activity in android

Tags: android-activity

I have 3 activities A , B, C. I call activity B from activity A, call C from B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I want to go back to activity A once from activity C, not create new activity A .

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by recall?

If you mean you want to go back to activity A once you are done with activity B, you could call `finish()` in activity B which will resume activity A.

Comment: I am so sorry, I updated my question, I have 3 activities, not 2 activities. I tried call finish(); , it will work if I have 2 activities.

Comment: You can call `finish()` in activity B after you start activity C and again call `finish()` in activity C. This should resume activity A.